# Few general questions about JavaFX capabilities

Tags: user-interface, javafx, exe, executable-jar, launch4j

I'm using JavaFX to build a GUI for the software I'm working on. I call it software but it's actually a series of automated steps, compiled into a standalone .exe file. I have about 6 of these executable files, which is why I'm building a GUI to act as the front-end, main menu of sorts.

Ideally I'd have the entire package (GUI, exes) combined into one file Jar which I'd then send to clients, or wrap it with JSmooth or Launch4j.

Questions:

1) Is it possible to combine all 6 .exe files into a package along with the GUI.? So if I click button 2 on the GUI, it runs .exe #2, etc. Which concepts should I understand?

2) Is this best practice, or is there a better method? I'm new to Java which is why I haven't built the entire software with it, just the GUI.

3) I've read that its best to extract the exe from the parent jar (or exe?) into a temp file on the users PC. Is this correct? Even for multiple wrapped exes?

Any answer is helpful. I'm trying to avoid building something only to realize I can't do what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to write an answer if you were a bit more specific regarding what those 6 .exe files do. Nevertheless, a few things can be pointed out. Answers are in the same order as questions.

1. Yes, you can package exe files into a jar. No, you can't run exe from within the jar. A common solution is to unpack exe either temporarily (while your application is active) or permanently, and then tell OS to execute it.
2. I'm not entirely sure what "best practice" refers to in your question. Ideally, your logic (back-end) code would be written in Java and all your 6 exe files would be a part of a single Java application. I respect that you are new to Java, so in your particular case having a front-end to your executables is perfectly fine. However, do keep in mind that your solution is Windows specific, unless you plan to provide other OS executables too.
3. Yes, you will need to extract the exe files. It doesn't really matter what parent executable you use (exe or jar). For the sake of simplicity, I'd go with the jar, because you won't need to use any 3rd party software to build such a jar.

Just to sum up, considering your situation, package your JavaFX app and the .exe files into a single executable jar. When the user needs to execute an ".exe", extract that ".exe" into the same directory where JavaFX is running from. When the app exits, delete all ".exe" files from that directory

Comment: Perfectly summed up! Thank you greatly AlmasB. Just to answer, each .exe does a different function. For instance, one will read from a text file and then manipulate the element values of a XML file based on the contents. Another one opens an automated browser, logs into a site, fills in fields and saves the output to a text file. Another one launches a series of API calls in order to provide the user with a variety of information about their location like neighbourhood, streets, establishments, etc. Some of this can definitely be done with Java, but for the time being I think the exe's are ok